# Using a header column as fixed value for y axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have data which looks like this (for the empty lines gnuplot won't draw anything, so I have an interrupted graph).

```
0,1,2,4,5,6
899.9999999999869,899.9999999999869,899.9999999999869,3602759.9999999995,845649.9999999999,899.9999999999869
842729.9999999999,842729.9999999999,842729.9999999999,5517769.999999999,3600219.9999999995,842729.9999999999
,,,,,
845649.9999999999,845649.9999999999,845649.9999999999,,,
3600219.9999999995,3600219.9999999995,3600219.9999999995,,,
```

Until now I had each of these columns in its separate file, and plotted it like this:

```
plot for [i=1:6] "".i.".dat" using 2:(i) with linespoints
```

The `(i)` causes gnuplot to draw a line through two points, all at a fixed y.

Can I do the same thing, but use the first row/the header for each column as a value for y? For example, The for the second column, I would like to plot with `plot "data.dat" using 2:(2)`, but where `(2)` is not hardcoded but is taken from the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your version of gnuplot is sufficiently recent.  Starting with (I think) version 5.2.2 the function "columhead(x)" can be evaluated inside a using specifier.  However it evaluates to a string, so it must be cast to a number before using it as a y coordinate value:

```
   set datafile separator comma
   plot for [i=1:6] "".i.".dat" using 2:(real(columnhead(i))) with linespoints title "column ".columnhead(i)
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly what I wanted!

In fact, my command is `plot for [i=1:6] "data.dat" every ::1 using i:(real(columnhead(i))) with linespoints title "column ".columnhead(i)`, because the columns are all in one file now, and to skip the header. Thank you!